# How to modify html table content using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm trying to update one of  table content for the confluence page using beautifulsoup and API requests.

this my code. I'm able to find and update the td but I couldn't insert the updated td into soup variable.

```
content=requests.get(address,headers=headers).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
for td in soup.find_all('td'):
if td == "<td> i need to update this </td>:
td.replace_with("<td>updated</td>")
```

i need the updated td to be inserted into soup variable, so when i search soup.find_all('td') i can find updated instead of i need to update this
how can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: Do not use regular expressions for parsing HTML.** I dearly hope that there is an alternative method for solving this problem. But, alas, I could not think of one.

Using the following regular expression, you can find every `td` element with no attributes attached. *This can be used for finding the elements, but don't try this for actually getting information from the elements*:

`<td>.*?</td>`

You can then use the `Pattern.sub()` method to substitute every instance of a `td` element with `<td>updated</td>`.

```py
import re

import bs4
import requests

content = requests.get(address, headers=headers).text
regex = re.compile(r"<td>.*?</td>")
new_content = regex.sub("<td>update</td>", content)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(new_content, features="html.parser")
```